# Best way to login to remote server after using Facebook login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm making an Android app that authenticates users via the Facebook SDK. However I also need to authenticate to a remote server in order to pull in new data for this user.

What's the best way to do this?

- Should I send the Facebook token to the remote server, then on the server use this to verify it's a valid token for this user and thus confirm the user's identity?
- Should I do the previous, but generate and send back my own token for the user to use in the future?
- If I later add Google authentication would something like this also work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

IMO, the best way would be

1. Authenticate user to Facebook from Android application
2. Get the FB auth token to the android app
3. Forward the authentication token & facebook UID from Android to web server
4. On web server, make Facebook API call with the submitted token, to verify the user

Comment: Just looking for same problem's solution and Found that given answer is not correct. Refer- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security/#tokenhijacking